# API v3 get multiple results for one field

Tags: api

I have a custom field that can be inserted multiple times in a contact. I'm trying to get the right syntax for the API to display an array with the different results.

Here what I'm trying: `civicrm/extern/rest.php?entity=Contact&action=get&api_key=userkey&key=sitekey&json={"sequential":1,"return":"custom_40","id":900}`

I thought that "sequential" would give multiple results but it's showing only one

{

```
"is_error": 0,
"version": 3,
"count": 1,
"id": 900,
"values": [
    {
        "contact_id": "900",
        "civicrm_value_fellowships_3_id": "305",
        "custom_40": "2007-06-30 00:00:00",
        "id": "900"
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contact API sends one result per contact. In case if you want to retrieve all custom field value(multiple) of a contact than you need to use CustomValue api. Snippet for reference

REST:

```
http://localhost/drupal7/sites/all/modules/civicrm/extern/rest.php?entity=CustomValue&action=get&api_key=userkey&key=sitekey&json={"sequential":1,"return":"custom_81,custom_80","entity_id":296,"entityType":"contact"}
```

PHP

```
$result = civicrm_api3('CustomValue', 'get', [
  'sequential' => 1,
  'return' => ["custom_81", "custom_80"],
  'entity_id' => 296,
  'entityType' => "contact",
]);
```

entity_id = contact id

return = custom fields

HTH

Pradeep